# How to write "sudo" commands and save it as terminal file?

Tags: gnome-terminal, ubuntu-gnome

Is possible to write some "sudo" commands with text app and save it as terminal file ?

It should allows me to run the saved commands directly batter than line by line and I can run it at any time ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a `.sh` file using any text editor.  Write the commands that you want to run each on it own line, and you can `add -y` to the end of the line for those that needs it, save the file with the extension `.sh`, and then you can run it from terminal.  See example below.

```
sudo -u ls /home/user/files
```

List the contents of the /home/user/files directory.

```
sudo apt install chromium-browser -y
```

Installs Chromium browser

Comment: Thanks, its works fine.. but as I understood, I can't run the commands when I double-clicked on the icon of file such as "cmd" or "bat" files in windows ?

Comment: You can create a launcher to do that.  See [Here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2436/how-can-i-create-a-application-launcher-for-a-sh-file)...